# amsart figure captions with TeXlive 2021

Tags: amsart, texlive-2021

I am finding misaligned figure captions when using TeXlive 2021 with amsart. A test file is here:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\hbox to\hsize{X\hfil \TeX{Live} 2021 on Mac\hfil X}

\begin{figure}[h]
\hbox to\hsize{X\hfil X\hfil X}
\caption{XXXXX}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The first hbox is just to show the margins. Running with TeXlive 2021 (June 2021) on Macosx 11.6, the caption is not centered:
[image: TeXlive 2021 output]

However, running with TeXlive 2019 on Ubuntu 20.04, the centering is correct:
[image: TeXlive 2019 output]
I have checked that the part of amsart.cls concerned with figure captions has not changed between these versions. Also, it doesn't make any difference whether latex or pdflatex is used. The problem only occurs for captions that fit on one line.

These are the only two versions of TeXlive that I have easy access to.

Comment: nice test file, thanks

Comment: this is now fixed in the public latex-dev  release

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Splendid!  I am impressed.

Comment: Setting `\captionindent=0pt` was a reasonable temporary work around for me pending the fix.

Comment: @AndrewSwann  Yes, except that if the caption needs more than one line, the appearance changes.  So this workaround needs to be applied only to short captions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original file works without error in LaTeX releases from

```
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> pre-release-2 (develop 2021-9-20 branch)
```

---

**Original answer**

The class needs to be updated for the 2021 latex release, an extra unkern is needed

**update** actually we will probably adjust things in the latex format so the following patch will not be necessary after the next latex release
https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/671

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\vbox{\color@setgroup
    \advance\hsize-2\captionindent\noindent
    \@captionfont\@captionheadfont#1\@xp\@ifnotempty\@xp
        {\@cdr#2\@nil}{.\@captionfont\upshape\enspace#2}%
    \unskip\kern-2\captionindent\par
    \global\setbox\@ne\lastbox\color@endgroup}%
  \ifhbox\@ne % the normal case
    \setbox\@ne\hbox{\unhbox\@ne\unskip\unskip\unpenalty\unkern\unkern}%
                                                               %%%%%%% extra unkern
  \fi
  \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa=\z@ % this means caption will fit on one line
    \setbox\@ne\hbox to\columnwidth{\hss\kern-2\captionindent\box\@ne\hss}%
  \else % tempboxa contained more than one line
    \setbox\@ne\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa\parskip\z@skip
        \noindent\unhbox\@ne\advance\hsize-2\captionindent\par}%
  \fi
  \ifnum\@tempcnta<64 % if the float IS a figure...
    \addvspace\abovecaptionskip
    \hbox to\hsize{\kern\captionindent\box\@ne\hss}%
  \else % if the float IS NOT a figure...
    \hbox to\hsize{\kern\captionindent\box\@ne\hss}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip\belowcaptionskip
  \fi
\relax
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\hbox to\hsize{X\hfil \TeX{Live} 2021 on Mac\hfil X}

\begin{figure}[h]
\hbox to\hsize{X\hfil X\hfil X}
\caption{XXXXX}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. As of today, that hasn't appeared in the TeXlive package update stream. Do you know if it is in the pipeline, or should I report it somewhere?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay no I meant it would need to be reported, but don't yet, just looking with the rest of the latex project team if we can tweak the latex change (related to the new paragraph hooks) so the class isn't affected. We'll ping the ams if needed.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay See note and link I just added to this answer